# Apex code executes in Salesforce1 offline mode?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, offline

I have couple of questions:

1. Can we access visualforce pages in offlice salesforce1 app?
2. if so, then if we have a controller attached to the page, the apex code and SOQL queries in the controller will execute or not?
3. When connection is available and SF offline data is getting synchronized with live, will it fire triggers and workflow rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Salesforce1 in offline mode for viewing, creating, editing, and deleting records. Salesforce1 does not support offline Visualforce pages. You can use the manifest attribute of a page to cache pages offline in your *browser*, however (e.g. Chrome, Firefox...), and they'll be supported by your browser. You cannot run Apex Code without connectivity to the server, nor query for data. You can only use the data you have locally stored on your device/browser.